# extracting info by host name, getaddrinfo() error

Tags: python, sockets, networking

```
import socket
host = "defined_here"
info = socket.getaddrinfo(host, 'http')
```

error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\PROGRAMMING\PYTHON\SMALL PACKS\wifireal.py", line 16, in 
info = socket.getaddrinfo(host, 'http')
File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed